# How to show multi select drop down with selected item

Tags: jquery

I using multi select drop down by this way

```
<script>
$('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
</script>
```

when we trying to show item with selected then its not showing item in the text box but item showing as selected. How to show selected item in the text box of the drop down? How does it possible with angular js? My script is as follows-

```
<script>
function PreSelectedDropDown() {
    var valArr = [1, 2];
    i = 0, size = valArr.length;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        $("#EditmultipleSelect option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").prop("selected", "Selected");
    }  
}
</script>
```

And reference link is [See the reference demo](https://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#EditmultipleSelect option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: hi, same is working but its not showing item in the text box. only showing selected when we check the item of drop down.

Comment: How does it possible with angular js

Comment: No followup questions in the comments please. Use the Ask Question button, if you have another question.

Comment: Where you have initialize the fastselect.. Before function or after function..If you have initialize before function 'PreSelectedDropDown', try after setting values.